# button overflow show ellipsis not working

Tags: html, css

Application requirement is display ... after the button reached division width. Once its reach need to display the ellipse. I have done partially but its not working as expected.

Hidding after text flowing out of the frame. it is causing problem for responsive design.

Please help me to fix this and thanks in advance

[For your reference check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaNAC.png)

```css
#margin {
    width: 57%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
}


.btn {
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 0 0 1px;
    margin: 1px 2px;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="margin">
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>
<span class="btn">1</span>

</div>
```

Comment: It's working. Showing *...* at the end of text. It will not hide DOM elements.

Comment: but its showing next hidden button as well

Comment: That is not text, but DOM element.

Comment: is there any way to hide that DOM elements ?

Comment: Yes, use JS: calculate how much items fits in your row and hide rest of them

Comment: cant we do it in css ?

Answer (score 0):

The `text-overflow: ellipsis` won't hide DOM elements, so the buttons themselves will show even if their containing text is hidden. If you want a CSS only solution you could try adding something like this to your CSS:

```
#margin {
  position:relative;
    width: 57%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
}

#margin::after {
  content:"...";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

This will add an element with an ellipsis inside and a white background to manually cover up the right side of `#margin`. The ellipsis will always be showing in a CSS solution, however you can hide and show it with a small amount of Javascript or jQuery. You can see a working [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dylanstark/czss1ot3/).

Comment: @KesavanR I've replaced the link with a working one. Hope this helps you.